# Google Maps - Using Replace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm trying to implement the Google Geocode API : HTML

```
<iframe width="500" height="375" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="{{googleMapSrc}}"></iframe>
```

Angular:

```
 scope.googleMapSrc = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + scope.tenantInfo.AddressLine1.Replace(/ /g, '+') + "," + scope.tenantInfo.City.replace(/ /g, '+') + "," + scope.tenantInfo.State + "&key=AIzaSyAs5ZGKka7IzIfkKx09-dU76-JV4OH5jH4"
```

The variable tenantInfo.AddressLine1 is entered as something like 1600 Baker Street, when it needs to be 1600+Baker+Street. Thus I am trying to use the .Replace to swap the spaces with +.

I keep on getting a typeError: Cannot read property "Replace of Undefined" and I'm not sure what's wrong.

Edit: and here is where the tenant address is set

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="edittenantaddress1" data-ng-bind="appConstants.Resources.AddressLine1_Label"></label>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <input type="text" id="edittenantaddress1" name="edittenantaddress1" class="form-control"
                               data-ng-model="editingTenant.AddressLine1"
                               data-ng-required="false"
                               placeholder="{{appConstants.Resources.AddressLine1_PlaceHolder}}"
                               maxlength="{{appConstants.Tenants.AddressLineLength}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: well from the error message it sounds like `scope.tenantInfo.AddressLine1` is undefined.  Where did you create that?  Your code doesn't show us.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive.

```
scope.tenantInfo.City.replace
```

is not the same as

```
scope.tenantInfo.AddressLine1.Replace
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

The 'replace' function is written in lowercase.

Change that latter one to

```
scope.tenantInfo.AddressLine1.replace
```

Comment: I just tried both cases, with .replace and .Replace. Neither work, I'm still getting the same error of "Cannot read property "r(R)eplace of undefined""

Comment: see my comment on your question.  You still need to show us where you think you're setting `scope.tenantInfo.AddressLine1` in your code.